# How to update Windows Phone from Ubuntu?

Tags: updates, phone

I don't have an access to Windows PC and I don't know how to update the OS of my phone.

In Windows OS I can use RUU software which does the job quite nicely, but I can't find any alternatives for Ubuntu.

I have HD2 phone which comes with Windows 6.5 OS and I have updated to custom Windows 6.5 OS.

How to update OS of my phone from Ubuntu 11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried throught VirtualBOX (with USB support) on a legacy virtual Windows installation?

Other solution, is to use a BartPE or Hiren's Boot CD with a "live" Windows environment... This can work if no other solution helps you!

Comment: Virtual machine is a big no in my case. My Ubuntu PC have a hard time supporting virtual boxes and it runs so slow that it freezes. The live Windows distribution seems like a nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since my OP I have bought a laptop with Windows 7 on it so it doesn't cause the problem anymore. Before that I have tried updating my phone from it's memory disk and I found no other way of updating phone without some virtual machine software or updating from memory card.

Yet, I still would like if there's a way just to know for future reference :)